# How to make Next.js show more informative source maps?

Tags: next.js, source-maps

I'm getting the following error from Next.js in dev mode:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

Call Stack

renderElement
file:/.../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6043:9)

renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:/.../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)

...

renderNodeDestructive
file:/.../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)

renderIndeterminateComponent
file:/.../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5785:7)
```

I know that something wrong with my imports, but after spending quite some time on debugging, I'm still stuck (I have 120+ source files in my project). The problem is that the call stack is only pointing out to `react-dom-server.browser.development.js`, but not to my source files.

Is there a way to enable more informative source mapping in Next.js that can help locating such errors?

Comment: Well... It turned out that imports in my source files were ok. Stopping Next.js and running it again from the terminal was the right solution.